# matplotlib fill_between() drawing unwanted extra lines to first/last point

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following script draws a red rectangle, but matplotlib is adding extra lines along the axes to the first/last points. How can I draw the red box without the red lines? Colab is running matplotlib `v3.2.2` by default, but if I upgrade to `v3.3.3` and restart the runtime, I still get the red lines.

```
def draw():
  # read in data
  x = [10, 10, 20, 20, 10]
  y = [10, 20, 20, 10, 10]

  # plot data
  ax.fill_between(x, y, color = 'red')
  ax.plot(x, y, color = 'black', linewidth = 2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  # We are running this script on its own
  import pandas as pd
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)      
  draw()
  plt.show()
```

Here is the screenshot of the result on google colab:
[image: red_box.ipynb]

Comment: according to the doc string, the signature for `fill_between` is `ax.fill_between(x, y1, y2=0)`. Yes, you would expect that line. Are you looking for [`Polygon`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Polygon.html) instead

Comment: It seems like `fill()` produces the desired effect instead of `fill_between()` or `Polygon`: `fill(x, y, color='red')` per [this matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/fill.html).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the "color" argument to "facecolor", and it should work

```
def draw():
  # read in data
  x = [10, 10, 20, 20, 10]
  y = [10, 20, 20, 10, 10]

  # plot data
  ax.fill_between(x, y, facecolor = 'red')
  ax.plot(x, y, color = 'black', linewidth = 2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  # We are running this script on its own
  import pandas as pd
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)      
  draw()
  plt.show()
```